# How to sort class using Comparator.comparing() depending on given criteria

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, java-8

I got following class which is not compilable code. I want to send criteria as a parameter to sort the employees array. How can I do it by using Comparator.comparing() in Java 8 functional style? For example, I want to sort it by name or by age, etc.

```
public class Employee {
        String name;
        int age;
        double salary;
        long mobile;    
}


public class EmpolyeeSorter {
    Employee[] employees = new Employee[]{
            new Employee("John", 25, 3000.0, 9922001),
            new Employee("Ace", 22, 2000.0, 5924001),
            new Employee("Keith", 35, 4000.0, 3924401)};


    public static void sortEmpoyeeByCriteria(Function<? super T, ? extends U> byCriteria) {
        Comparator<Employee> employeeComparator
                = Comparator.comparing(byCriteria);

    }
}
```

Comment: Just think about it; what is `T` here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a bit the definition of the of your method:

```
public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> void sortEmpoyeeByCriteria(Function<? super T, ? extends U> byCriteria) {
        Comparator<T> c = Comparator.comparing(byCriteria);
}
```

You should also pass the `List` to that method that you want to sort in this case.

But then why not use `Collections.sort` in this case and pass the `List` and the `Comparator` in the form (for example):

```
Collections.sort(yourList, Comparator.comparing(Employee::getXXX))
```

**EDIT**
You could declare it like this:

```
public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> void sortEmpoyeeByCriteria(
            List<T> list,
            Function<? super T, ? extends U> byCriteria) {
        Comparator<? super T> c = Comparator.comparing(byCriteria);
        list.sort(c);
}
```

Comment: I can do it by Collections.sort(yourList, Comparator.comparing(Employee::getXXX)) easily. But I wanted to pass Employee::getXXX as parameter. Aslo I didn't understand how to use this code  public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> void sortEmpoyeeByCriteria(Function<? super T, ? extends U> byCriteria) {
        Comparator<T> c = Comparator.comparing(byCriteria);
} Please how to do use it?

Comment: It is working fine. But could you please explain the method signature <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> void sortEmpoyeeByCriteria ?? It is <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> void ?? Really confused is it void or <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>>  ?? How is it working?

Comment: @masiboo: in this case, it’s as simple as looking at [the signature of `Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-). You have to use compatible type parameters to declare a `Function` parameter that can be passed to that method…

Answer (score 1):

You can use a reference method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee[] employees = new Employee[] { new Employee("John", 25, 3000.0, 9922001),
            new Employee("Ace", 22, 2000.0, 5924001), new Employee("Keith", 35, 4000.0, 3924401) };


    Comparator<Employee> comparingAge = Comparator.comparing(Employee::getAge);
    Comparator<Employee> comparingName = Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName);
    Comparator<Employee> comparingSalary = Comparator.comparing(Employee::getSalary);

    Arrays.sort(employees, comparingAge);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(employees));

    Arrays.sort(employees, comparingName);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(employees));

    Arrays.sort(employees, comparingSalary);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(employees));
}
```

---

you can do too:

```
    sortMe(employees, comparingAge);
    sortMe(employees, comparingName);
    sortMe(employees, comparingSalary);
```

where sortme is :

```
private static void sortMe(Employee[] employees, Comparator<Employee> comparingCriteria) {
    Arrays.sort(employees, comparingCriteria);
}
```

Comment: I knew I can use Comparator.comparing(Employee::XXX). But I wanted to send a comparison criterion by function parameter. Btw, what is Comparator<Employee> c = (o1, o2) -> 0; is doing?

Comment: Yes, after your code. I started to think similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Tried lambda approach in Comparator.comparing()

```
class Employee {

  String name;
  int age;
  double salary;
  long mobile;

public Employee(String name, int age, double salary, long mobile) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.salary = salary;
    this.mobile = mobile;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
public double getSalary() {
    return salary;
}
public void setSalary(double salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}
public long getMobile() {
    return mobile;
}
public void setMobile(long mobile) {
    this.mobile = mobile;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee [name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", salary=" + salary + ", mobile=" + mobile + "]";
 }
}


public class MainClass
 {
    public static List<Employee> getEmployee()
    {
        List<Employee> ob = new ArrayList<>();
        ob.add(new Employee("John", 25, 3000.0, 9922001));
        ob.add(new Employee("Ace", 22, 2000.0, 5924001));
        ob.add(new Employee("Keith", 35, 4000.0, 3924401));
        return ob;
    }

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        List<Employee> ob = getEmployee();

        System.out.println("Sort By Name");
        ob.sort(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getName()));
        System.out.println(ob);

        System.out.println("Sort By Age");
        ob.sort(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getAge()));
        System.out.println(ob);         
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Sort By Name
[Employee [name=Ace, age=22, salary=2000.0, mobile=5924001], Employee [name=John, age=25, salary=3000.0, mobile=9922001], Employee [name=Keith, age=35, salary=4000.0, mobile=3924401]]
Sort By Age
[Employee [name=Ace, age=22, salary=2000.0, mobile=5924001], Employee [name=John, age=25, salary=3000.0, mobile=9922001], Employee [name=Keith, age=35, salary=4000.0, mobile=3924401]]
```

Hope this help!!